# Generating a notification on Facebook profile picture change

Tags: facebook

I am working on a Chrome extension that generates a notification whenever an entered Facebook profile changes his/her profile picture. I want to know if it is possible to do so using the Facebook API. I know we can get the current profile picture of the person using the API but how can we generate the notification? Please guide. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That´s what the Realtime API is for: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/

I assume it would be the `picture` subscription of the `User` object.

Answer (score 0):

What @luschn said is correct, you can use the Realtime Updates API. Would I want to add is that you can't receive the Realtime Updates client-side, which means that you need to set up some backend infrastructure before you can use them. Your Chrome extension "frontend" then need to be notified on a change by your backend...

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.3#setup